# Can't seem to get the code to rename a folder in php

Tags: php, forms, rename

I have a form which takes in a `newuserId` in which if the user wants to change his `userId`, I have to change the folder name as well. This is in the html code:

```
New UserID: <input type="text" size="8" name="newUserId">
```

In my php code I have this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if(!empty($_POST['newFirstName']))
{
    $oldFolder = "profileImages/$userToUpdate";
    $newFolder = "profileImages/$newUserId";
    $renameSuccess = rename($oldFolder, $newFolder);
    if($renameSuccess)
    {
        $renameStatus = true;   
    }

    else
    {
        $renameStatus = false ;
    }
}
```

`$userToUpdate` would be the old `userId`.

Comment: Did you check the permission run this script?

Comment: Turn on error reporting and check id there is any issue while renaming

Comment: how do I check for permissions?

Comment: I have previously used commands to create and delete folders mkdir and rmdir so I'm assuming I have perms?

Comment: Ahhh I figured it out... I placed the wrong var name in the if condition!!